# adding asp application to Vs 2010 and debugging it

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have an asp application that has developed long back and want to debug it in 2010.
can anyone tell me how to add the asp application to VS 2010 and debug the asp code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to add an existing classic ASP application into Visual Studio and then debug it on a web server.  I don't believe that is possible.  Visual Studio removed classic ASP debugging support in Visual Studio 2005.

It was possible with a bit of work to get ASP debugging support into Visual Studio 2005.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2006/03/15/552108.aspx

I don't know if this trick works in newer versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: I think there should be a way to do it.

Comment: @user1078389 the article I referenced was written by the team which formerly owned classic ASP script debugging. If their trick doesn't work then I'd say it's unlikely you'll find a way to make this work.